# How can I increase memory allocated to GlassFish?

Tags: java, glassfish-3

I would like to increase my memory allocation to my GlassFish instance. Could anyone please help me out. Your answer could be via the admin console or the command line, I don't mind.

Comment: Same as other servers I imagine... Pass an argument in the VM options part to increase the relevant memory...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the -Xmx and other properties in the admin console as described [here](http://www.binbert.com/blog/2010/04/glassfish-performance-tunning/).

Answer (score 17):

Find a file domain.xml which you are using, i.e.

/usr/local/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml

(if using Linux you can use "locate domain.xml" (if you have mlocate installed and do "sudo updatedb"). If you use other operating systems, find manually your glassfish directory and the domain file.

Find memory settings there (Xmx) in that file and others and change it.