# How to allocate the maximum available RAM to GlassFish?

Tags: java, linux, memory-management, glassfish, jvm

I am not a pro so please bear with me!
I rent a server (Linux, Debian) with 24Gb RAM with Glassfish 3.1 running on it (nothing else installed).

The app deployed on GlassFish runs very computationally intensive methods. How can I set the memory settings of GlassFish (and the JDK??) so that my app can utilize the 24Gb if necessary?

Comment: you can allocate maximum of 6GB to jvm

Comment: @www.sblog.in There are some reasons why one might not recommend allocating more than 6GB to the JVM, but in *no way* is 6GB a maximum of any sort on a modern 64-bit OS.

Comment: @William Price it's not OS rather depends on RAM size

Comment: It is OS dependent (a single process on a 32-bit OS cannot address >4GB) and only partly dependent upon RAM size -- look up *virtual memory*.  Even then, it is not difficult to get access to a machine that has 48+ GB of physical RAM available to the system.  I have supported JVMs running with 100+GB of heap space.

Comment: Hi, sorry this is is not a duplicate at all IMHO. My question precisely asks how to allocate the max avail. RAM, the "Memory management on Glassfish" asks "What settings or methodologies can I apply to minimize these memory leaks?". I need an answer to my question and it is not addressed in previous ones!

Comment: Tx to commenters, may I ask them what params they'd generally advise on glassfish and the jvm for my 64-bit, 24RAM system?

Comment: Very probably, your 64 bits JVM will use available RAM.

Comment: So do I need to add <jvm-options>-Xmx24G</jvm-options> to domain.xml?

Comment: There are related links in the right hand column of this page.  A quick search will reveal [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468189/how-can-i-increase-memory-allocated-to-glassfish), too.  And this is probably covered in the Glassfish documentation on its own site.

Comment: "And this is probably covered in the Glassfish documentation on its own site" -> no.